# Python selenium cannot switch windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to switch to a pop-up window through python and selenium, but I'm getting this error:

```
    first_window = driver.current_window_handle()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url-here")
first_window = current_window_handle()
login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('anon-only')
login_button.click()


windows = driver.window_handles()
for window in windows:
    if (window != first_window):
        driver.switch_to_window(window)
```

I'm not sure why driver.current_window_handle() is returning a str. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

driver.window_handles is a property not a function, so it’s just `windows = driver.window_handles`.